# Add new SQL record, taking ID from current php?id=

Tags: php, sql

I realise I'm probably being the biggest noob there has ever been, but this has driven me mad all day...

So basically I've got 1 table called 'clients' with basic client details in... I've managed a search.php, view.php and edit.php to show and edit the client search results, but I want an 'Add Project' button under each search result which links to newproject.php, where the ID of the client I am currently viewing is populated into the form, so I can 'create a new project' with the client's details without having to put them in again - I've tried different things all day to absolutely no avail, I'm at the point now where I'm clearly missing the most basic solution!

Any help would be so hugely appreciated!

```
    // connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

// get results from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

// display data in table
echo "<p><b>View All</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>View Paginated</a></p>";

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['LastName'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 

// close table>
echo "</table>";
```

Is the view.php

```
$sql="INSERT INTO projects (projectname, budget)
VALUES
('$_POST[projectname]','$_POST[budget]')";
 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Is the insertproject.php

```
<form action="insertproject.php" method="post">
Project Name: <input type="text" name="projectname" /><br><br>
Budget: <input type="text" name="budget" /><br><br>
```

Is newproject.php

For some reason I've got the idea in my head that I want a textbox pre-populated with GET ID from the URL to go straight into the project form...

If it sounds more simple to you than it does to me then you deserve a Nobel Prize!

Comment: Please show us some code :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the client_id to `newproject.php` and collect the `client_id` in the `newproject.php` and put the value in a hidden field inside the form.

In Search Results Page Add

```
<a href="newproject.php?client_id=<?php echo $clientID; ?>">Add Project </a>
```

In newproject.php Page

```
<?php
$clientId = $_REQUEST['client_id']
?>
<form method="post" action="newproject.php">
<input type="hidden" name="client_id" id="client_id" value="<?php echo $clientId;?>"/>
-----------------
Your Project Form
-----------------
</form>
```

Comment: I've updated the search results and changed the code in newproject.php, but I want to view the client_id so I changed 'hidden' to 'text' and the box is blank when I click the link to a new project.

Comment: Check your URL: It should be like http://yourdomainname/newproject.php?client_id=12.Also check whether you have requested the client_id (in $clientId = $_REQUEST['client_id'] ) newproject.php.I hope you missed out some step or misspelled the variable name.For quick understanding you may post your code code snippet.